# Java - add element to ArrayList with unknown order

Tags: java, collections

Found an interesting thing about ArrayList,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(0, "0-element");
list.add(1, "1-element");
list.add(2, "2-element");
```

But if the elements are not coming in an unknown order, eg.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(1, "1-element");  // IndexOutOfBoundsException
list.add(2, "2-element");
list.add(0, "0-element");
```

You get IndexOutOfBoundsException, Is the only option here is to use a Map instead of List?

Comment: I don't get your use case. Why are you doing this ?

Comment: The idiomatic usage is `list.add(E)`, index is rarely used unless there is a reason to insert at a specific index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) :

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index > size())

You could test before adding :

```
if (pos>=list.size()) list.add(element);
else list.add(pos, element);
```

But what you do is strange (and that's the reason why there is no method doing the test and adding/insertion). Do you really want to add at index (i.e. moving some of the previously inserted elements) ? Are you sure a standard array, allowing you to set elements at arbitrary index isn't what you need ?

Comment: I guess my case just fit in Map better than list.

Answer (score 4):

More or less, yeah.  You can't have a `List` in a state where there's an element at index `i` but not `i-1`; you can't add an element at an index that doesn't currently exist in the `List`.

Comment: Perfect and concise explanation +1

Answer (score 3):

If you read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29), it says:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
>   **throws** IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

So in your first example, the list is empty and an element is inserted in position 0 (which does not exist yet but is the first available - index = 0 <= size() = 0).

In your second example, you try to insert in position 1 but there is nothing in position 0 yet so it fails (index = 1 > size() = 0).

Answer (score 1):

Just check `add` method implementation in ArrayList then you will get the answer

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    if (index > size || index < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
        "Index: "+index+", Size: "+size);

    ensureCapacity(size+1);  // Increments modCount!!
    System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
             size - index);
    elementData[index] = element;
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Smply use

```
list.add("element1");
list.add("element2");
list.add("element3);
```

The reason why you get that IndexOutOfBoundsException, is that you want to acces element 1 which does not yet exist.

From the docuof ArrayList

```
Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you list doesn't contain duplicates, and you don't care about the order, then you can use `Set<String>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `ArrayList` as `List`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("...");
```

I think you also should use a `Set` instead of a `List`.